# Remove clearly not visible vertices from a polygon

Tags: 2d, polygon

[image]

For a visibility algorithm I want to remove verts of polygon that are guaranteed not visible from a vert S. The idea is to remove pockets that points are on the backside of a plane formed by the vector n, the perpendicular vector between S and 0, and a point S.

The prerequisites are:

- the points of a polygon are in ccw order
- the labeled points are the cutting-points between g(t) and the edges of the polygon

  - sorted by occurrence with respect to S
  - only the points with a positive t are retained
  - the points are part of a new created polygon, we are working with

The difficult task is to identify a pocket respectively the pair of indices a pocket starts and ends.

Here are my approaches:

1. Use the natural order of cutting-points and remove items with a smaller t to their previous ones (works on I, III and IV).
2. Sort the cutting-points by t. If the second point has the highest index in the original order, then all other cutting-points are part of the pocket and can be ignored (works on II).

Now the questions are:

1. When should I use the first and when the second approach (I can't see it)?
2. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. Here is a result:

[image]

The example is out of this post: [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4507/finding-the-nearest-neighbor-of-polygons)

Comment: It would be great to have a summary of what made the difference and how it helped.